# SQL server OPENJSON, best approach to display JSON raw string along with feilds

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to select the results from JSON file using `OPENJSON()` in TSQL:

```
ask_price,  bid_price,  mark_price  ,high_price ,low_price  ,open_price ,KEY ,value
```

I am able to get the values but it contains duplicate. It should return only 3 rows but as you can see it is 9 rows.

I tried to use distinct and group by but still have duplicates and it may affect the performance. Is there any alternative which I can use?

```
DECLARE @JSONData AS NVARCHAR(4000) 

SET @JSONData = N'{ "results":[ { "ask_price":"377.360000", "open_price":"376.475000","symbol":"BCHUSD","id":"24566"},
      { "ask_price":"9668.090000","open_price":"9642.645000","symbol":"BTCUSD","id":"32555"},
      {"ask_price":"262.660000", "open_price":"260.890000","symbol":"ETHUSD","id":"356789"} ] }'      

SELECT Y.*, Z.[KEY],Z.[value]  FROM OPENJSON(@JSONData) AS x CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(x.value) WITH ( ask_price numeric(18,12), open_price numeric(18,12) ) AS Y CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(@JSONData, '$.results') as Z
```

RESULTS

```
Current results 

ask_price   open_price  KEY value
377.360000000000    376.475000000000    0   { "ask_price":"377.360000", "open_price":"376.475000","symbol":"BCHUSD","id":"24566"}
377.360000000000    376.475000000000    1   { "ask_price":"9668.090000","open_price":"9642.645000","symbol":"BTCUSD","id":"32555"}
377.360000000000    376.475000000000    2   {"ask_price":"262.660000", "open_price":"260.890000","symbol":"ETHUSD","id":"356789"}
9668.090000000000   9642.645000000000   0   { "ask_price":"377.360000", "open_price":"376.475000","symbol":"BCHUSD","id":"24566"}
9668.090000000000   9642.645000000000   1   { "ask_price":"9668.090000","open_price":"9642.645000","symbol":"BTCUSD","id":"32555"}
9668.090000000000   9642.645000000000   2   {"ask_price":"262.660000", "open_price":"260.890000","symbol":"ETHUSD","id":"356789"}
262.660000000000    260.890000000000    0   { "ask_price":"377.360000", "open_price":"376.475000","symbol":"BCHUSD","id":"24566"}
262.660000000000    260.890000000000    1   { "ask_price":"9668.090000","open_price":"9642.645000","symbol":"BTCUSD","id":"32555"}
262.660000000000    260.890000000000    2   {"ask_price":"262.660000", "open_price":"260.890000","symbol":"ETHUSD","id":"356789"}


Expected results 

    ask_price   open_price  KEY value
377.360000000000    376.475000000000    0   { "ask_price":"377.360000", "open_price":"376.475000","symbol":"BCHUSD","id":"24566"}
9668.090000000000   9642.645000000000   1   { "ask_price":"9668.090000","open_price":"9642.645000","symbol":"BTCUSD","id":"32555"}
262.660000000000    260.890000000000    2   {"ask_price":"262.660000", "open_price":"260.890000","symbol":"ETHUSD","id":"356789"}
```

Comment: Ensure to provide a test case with *minimally relevant data* that shows the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following query will do the trick:

```
SELECT resdata.*, res.[KEY], res.[Value] FROM OPENJSON(@JSONData) AS resTab 
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(resTab.value) AS res
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(res.value)
WITH ( ask_price numeric(18,12), bid_price numeric(18,12),  mark_price numeric(18,12),  
        high_price numeric(18,12),   low_price numeric(18,12),  open_price numeric(18,12) ) AS resdata
```

Answer (score 1):

You may consider the next two approaches, which return the expected results:

JSON:

```
DECLARE @JSONData AS NVARCHAR(4000) 
SET @JSONData = N'{
   "results":[
      {
         "ask_price":"377.360000",
         "open_price":"376.475000",
         "symbol":"BCHUSD",
         "id":"24566"
      },
      {
         "ask_price":"9668.090000",
         "open_price":"9642.645000",
         "symbol":"BTCUSD",
         "id":"32555"
      },
      {
         "ask_price":"262.660000",
         "open_price":"260.890000",
         "symbol":"ETHUSD",
         "id":"356789"
      }
   ]
}'
```

Statement, using `OPENJSON()` and `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT j2.ask_price, j2.open_price, j1.[key], j1.[value]
FROM OPENJSON(@JSONData, '$.results') j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value]) WITH (
   ask_price numeric(18, 6) '$.ask_price', 
   open_price numeric(18, 6) '$.open_price'
) j2
```

Statement, using `OPENJSON()` and `JSON_VALUE()`:

```
SELECT 
   JSON_VALUE([value], '$.ask_price') AS ask_price,
   JSON_VALUE([value], '$.open_price') AS open_price,
   [key], 
   [value]
FROM OPENJSON(@JSONData, '$.results')
```

Result:

```
------------------------------------------------------
ask_price   open_price  key value
------------------------------------------------------
377.360000  376.475000  0   {
                            "ask_price":"377.360000",
                            "open_price":"376.475000",
                            "symbol":"BCHUSD",
                            "id":"24566"
                            }
9668.090000 9642.645000 1   {
                            "ask_price":"9668.090000",
                            "open_price":"9642.645000",
                            "symbol":"BTCUSD",
                            "id":"32555"
                            }
262.660000  260.890000  2   {
                            "ask_price":"262.660000",
                            "open_price":"260.890000",
                            "symbol":"ETHUSD",
                            "id":"356789"
                            }
```

Notes:

`JSON_VALUE()` returns a single text value of type `nvarchar(4000)`, so you need to convert this value to the appropriate data type.